FastAPI raises "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"
I am trying to build an application which stores some users and their sales records. There is a register_user API which sends the user data to the db.
However, when I trigger the API in localhost:8000/docs after running python -m main:app, I get RecursionError while I dont have any recursion calls in the implementation.
The code in main.py is as follows:
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Request
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from passlib.context import CryptContext


SQLALCHEMY_DB_URL = "sqlite:///./records.db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DB_URL, connect_args = {"check_same_thread": False}
)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, 
                            autoflush=False,
                            bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()


class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    business_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    phone_number = Column(String, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False)
    hashed_password = Column(String, nullable=False)


Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


app = FastAPI()

bcrypt_context = CryptContext(schemes=['bcrypt'], deprecated='auto')



def get_password_hash(password: str):
    return bcrypt_context.hash(password)

def get_db():
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@app.post('/register') 
async def register_user(request:Request,
                        email: str, 
                        business_name: str,
                        phone_number: str,
                        password: str,
                        password2: str,
                        db: Session = Depends(get_db)
                        ):
    try:
        validation1 = db.query(Users) \
                        .filter(Users.phone_number == phone_number) \
                        .first()
        
        validation2 = db.query(Users) \
                        .filter(Users.email == email) \
                        .first()

        if password != password2 or validation1 is not None or validation2 is not None:
            msg = "Invalid Registration Request"
            return {"request": request, 
                "msg": msg}
        
        user_model = Users()
        user_model.email = email
        user_model.phone_number = phone_number
        user_model.business_name = business_name
        user_model.hashed_password = get_password_hash(password=password)

        db.add(user_model)
        db.commit()

        msg = "User Successfully Created"

        return {"request": request, 
            "msg": msg}

    except Exception as e:

        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        msg = "Internal Server Error"
        return {"request": request, "msg": msg}

The code should have committed the new user to the db, however the code just fails with some errors which I am not able to decode.
The traceback is as follows. The first few lines:
INFO:     127.0.0.1:52561 - "POST /auth/register?email=email%40email.com&business_name=business&phone_number=1234567890&password=pass123&password2=pass123 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 398, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 70, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 123, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 186, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 164, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 65, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 756, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 776, in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 297, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 77, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 72, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 296, in app
    content = await serialize_response(
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 180, in serialize_response
    return jsonable_encoder(response_content)
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 289, in jsonable_encoder
    encoded_value = jsonable_encoder(
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 333, in jsonable_encoder
    return jsonable_encoder(
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 289, in jsonable_encoder
    encoded_value = jsonable_encoder(
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 333, in jsonable_encoder
    return jsonable_encoder( 

The last 3 lines here are repeated numerous times. Finally closing off with
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 216, in jsonable_encoder
    if isinstance(obj, BaseModel):
  File "C:\Users\<User>\sales_register\env\lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_model_construction.py", line 248, in __instancecheck__
    return hasattr(instance, '__pydantic_validator__') and super().__instancecheck__(instance)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Your suggestions will be much helpful.
If the codebase is needed, I would be okay with sharing.

Show at least the first and last few lines of the traceback as properly formatted text (as code) in the question.

Are you that it's this function that's recursing?

@MichaelButscher I have added in the traceback now. Should have added in it in the first instance. Apologies.

@SIGHUP I am not quite sure, where it is coming from. It is the only function that is being called in the API with one other which is just a return statement with a call to CryptContext.hash()

The issue is with your endpoint returning the Request instance in the response, that is:
from fastapi import Request

@router.post('/register') 
async def register_user(request: Request,...
     ...
     return {"request": request, "msg": msg}
                        ^^^^^^^

That is actually what causes the following error:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Removing that should fix the issue for you. Plus, it does not make that sense to return a Python object in the response that would look like this:
<starlette.requests.Request object at 0x000...>


It worked. Thanks a lot. Could you please explain how you were able to pinpoint the error location here as it was not in the traceback.?

At first glance, returning the Request object seemed off. Then, the jsonable_encoder(), shown at the end of your traceback, is a function used internally by FastAPI when returning a response, in order to ensure that objects that are not serializable are converted to str. Please take a look at this answer for more details on that.
